# Incorporate a list of floats, into another list of floats, in numerical order, with remainders

Tags: list, sorting

In this example, there is a list of miscellaneous orphan floats `'(9.9 10.1 10.3 10.5 10.7 10.9 11.1)` that needs to be incorporated *in numerical order* into a second *main / master* list `(10.0 10.2 10.4 10.6 10.8 11.0)`, with the *hard* bounds being `car` and `(cdr (last ...))`; i.e., the orphan floats will be *remainders* if they are less than `car` or greater than `(cdr (last ...))` of the *main / master* list.  The end result for the *main / master* list will be `'(10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11.0)`, and the end result for the remainders will be `'(9.9 11.1)`.  How can this be accomplished programmatically by an Emacs user?

[My only thoughts of an approach at this point in time are using the `ring` library to give me `next` and `previous` of the selected item while looping through the main list; however, I suspect there is a better approach.]

**EDIT**:  Example output of solution:  `'((remainders (9.9 11.1)) (master (10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11.0)))`

Comment: What happened to `10.0`?

Comment: Both lists above are sorted - is that always the case?

Comment: @ NickD -- the main / master list will always be sorted numerically, however, the orphan list that will end up having some remainders is not going to be sorted; i.e., a few zeros, a few 0.03, a few 0.05, and some floats what will fall within the parameters of the main / master list.  For duplicates, that fall within the main / master list, I will be creating a list of text properties containing details of each element being incorporated that matched -- however, that is not needed for a minimal working example.

Comment: So you want to sort the unsorted list, and merge with the original list.  Or just combine the two as-is and sort the result.  You know that `sort` exists, yes?

Comment: @phils --thank you.  The orphan list does not need to be sorted, and the remainder list does not need to be sorted.  The main / master list, however, should be sorted.

Comment: @phils: except that some elements of the orphan list (the ones smaller than the smallest element of the main list and larger than the largest elements of the main list) have to be thrown out into the remainder list.

Comment: @NickD -- thank you ... the remainders need to be tracked; i.e., those that will not fall within the parameters of the main master / list.  So, there will be two (2) different aspects, e.g., `'((remainders (9.9 11.1)) (master (10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11.0)))` or similar format.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So extract out the "remainder" items from the orphans as a first step, and then proceed as before?  Also seconding the question "what happened to 10.0?".

Comment: @phils -- good catch! -- I'll fix that now.  Thank you.  Separating the orphans that fall outside the parameters of the main / master list as a first step sounds like a good logical approach towards a solution.  I'll add an example alist result desired ..., but it could be in a different format so long as there are two separate lists ....

Comment: I would say break the problem into small pieces... first sort your lists (which they are already), then create empty remainder and 'new-main' lists. Then, using while loops, first push all 'initial' remainders to the remainders list. Subsequently, using another while loop, merge lists (into the `new-main` list) and finally concatenate (append) the 'initial' remainders with the 'final' remainders. I am not sure if it will be helpful to post the answer here (depending on if you'd prefer to learn or just want the answer). After this, extending with duplicates list will be quite straightforward...

Comment: Here the while loops should be destructive 'list-eaters': `(setq list (cdr list))`

Comment: @dalanicolai -- thank you for the idea.  The tool `cl-merge` is something that I was unaware of until seeing your comment and the answer from `d125q` below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```lisp
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun incorporate (master orphans)
  (let* (;; remove call to `cl-sort' if `master' is already sorted
         (master (cl-sort (cl-copy-list master) #'<))
         ;; remove call to `cl-sort' if `orphans' is already sorted
         (orphans (cl-sort (cl-copy-list orphans) #'<))
         (lb (car master))
         (ub (car (last master)))
         (pred (lambda (elem) (or (< elem lb) (> elem ub))))
         (to-incorporate (cl-remove-if pred orphans))
         (remainders (cl-remove-if-not pred orphans)))
    (list (list 'remainders remainders)
          ;; since both `master' and `to-incorporate' are sorted, we can use `cl-merge'
          (list 'master (cl-merge 'list (cl-copy-list master) to-incorporate #'<)))))

(incorporate '(10.0 10.2 10.4 10.6 10.8 11.0)
             '(9.9 10.1 10.3 10.5 10.7 10.9 11.1))
```

returns

```lisp
'((remainders (9.9 11.1))
  (master (10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11.0)))
```

Why do you think the `ring` library would help with this problem?

Comment: Thank you ... I will try out this answer later in the day when back at the computer.  I had initially thought of the `ring` library because it provides a preview of what is next, whereas, the basic `while` or `mapc` would necessitate an additional check of the current's position in the list to locate what would be next.  Along those lines, at each element of the master list, knowing what is next, I was thinking of looping through the remainders to see if anything should be inserted.  Then, I was thinking of inserting the remainders at the right location. However, I knew that idea was awkward.

Answer (score 2):

So as @d125q has posted a nice high level solution (where he could also have used the `map-merge` and `seq-remove/sort` variants), I will post my somewhat lower level 'list-eater' style solution (for completeness, and in addition to my comment). The solution might read a little less nicely than the high level solution, but the steps are very intuitive and logical.

```lisp
;; First sort your lists (which they already are here), and create the
;; `remainders' and `new-main' lists
(let ((orphan '(9.9 10.1 10.3 10.5 10.7 10.9 11.1))
      (main '(10.0 10.2 10.4 10.6 10.8 11.0))
      remainders new-main)


  ;; then 'eat' orphan and push to remainders as long (car orphan) is smaller
  ;; than (car main)
  (while (< (car orphan) (car main))
    (push (car orphan) remainders)
    (setq orphan (cdr orphan)))

  ;; now 'eat' both lists, take a bite depending on which has the smallest
  ;; 'car', and push to `new-main', as long as there are members in main
  (while main
    (let ((o (car orphan))
          (m (car main)))
      (cond ((< o m)
             (push o new-main)
             (setq orphan (cdr orphan)))
            (t
             (push m new-main)
             (setq main (cdr main))))))


  ;; subsequently because the push prepends elements, nreverse the `remainder' and
  ;; the `new-main' lists, and append final remainders to initial remainders. I
  ;; use cons as I don't know why you would want the cdr's of the elements to be
  ;; nested lists
  (list (cons 'remainders (append (nreverse remainders)
                                  orphan))
        (cons 'main (nreverse new-main))))
```

when I say bite, I mean taking the cdr of the list for the next iteration (from the books 'land of lisp' or 'realm of racket').

Finally, I set the results as cdr directly using cons instead of 'adding' an extra (seemingly redundant) list around it.

Extending the algorithm to handle duplicates should be quite straightforward (handle the case when both cars are equal, and check if new-main already contains the element before pushing).

Comment: I have removed a redundant step, and while doing that, I have added a hint for how to extend the algorithm to handle duplicates.